# How to set url pattern in web.xml for Coldfusion CFClickJackFilterDeny

Tags: coldfusion, clickjacking

I'm trying to resolve a clickjacking vulnerability for a web site that I'm working on which uses ColdFusion 11.  It seems that I'm having problems with the URL pattern on the production site though.  Right now I have:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterSameOrigin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/CFIDE/administrator/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterDeny</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ABC/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The first part is the default, but since I don't use frames in the site, I would like to have it default to deny for anything else.

The problem that I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the url-pattern right.  On my development server, I use "http://localhost/abc" to access my working version.  However on the production site, the url follows the pattern "https://abc.def.xyz.com".  If I use "ABC" as the url pattern, as I have above, it works on the development site, but not on the production site.  So, I'm obviously missing something about how to set up the url pattern.  I think if I just used /*, I would end up locking down (with deny) everything including the admin, which is not exactly what I want.

I don't usually have to work on the server settings, etc., but the person who does was in an accident and is in the hospital, so that just leaves me. Any thoughts on how to set the correct url pattern to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: The `filter-mapping` options only allow you to specify `url-pattern` _which occur after the domain name_. This works for your dev server but it looks like your production server is using sub-domains instead (_before the domain name_). You need to look at settings via your web server. Perhaps sending the `X-Frame-Options` header instead.

Comment: Changing the web.config to send a x-frame-options header worked for me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, glad that helped you. I will add a proper answer so that others can see it when they find your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Promoted from the comments*

The `filter-mapping` options only allow you to specify `url-pattern` **which occur after the domain name**. This works for your dev server but it looks like your production server is using sub-domains instead (**which occur before the domain name**). You need to look at settings via your web server. Perhaps sending the `X-Frame-Options` header instead.

From OWASP [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet - Defending with X-Frame-Options Response Headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Defending_with_X-Frame-Options_Response_Headers)

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a  or . Sites can use this to avoid Clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. Set the X-Frame-Options header for all responses containing HTML content. The possible values are "DENY", "SAMEORIGIN", or "ALLOW-FROM uri"